# Add dynamic ASP.NET controls via a DropDownList to the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, controls

**- Primary Info:**
In my recent project, I need to have a page with a DropDownList with some items like 'firstName' , 'lastName' , 'Age' and etc. I want to add optional controls to the page when every item selected by user. For example when user select the 'Age' another dropdownlist created dynamically with these values : 'Less than 10'
'Between 10 and 30'
'more than 30'
Here is a button that add this user selection to listBox and let user to choice another options. (I made a query at last according to user choices and send it to db)
**- What I do:**
I create a dropDownList and set it's *AutoPostBack* property to *true* and adds some items in it and user must select one of those item. then I add user SelectedValue of dropDownList in a Cache variable before page post back happens:

```
protected void DropDownListColumnNameSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cache["SelectedKey"] = dropDownListColumnName.SelectedValue;
    }
```

When user select an item from dropDownList *DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged* fire, and I must create controls dynamically in a place holder:

```
 var textBoxName = new TextBox
    {
        ID = "textBoxName",
        CssClass = "str-search-textbox-highlight",
        ViewStateMode = ViewStateMode.Disabled
    };
 placeHolderFirstItem.Controls.Add(textBoxName);
```

**- What is the problem?**
When I try add new control in current Button_Click event, control added successfully to page but I can't find it by *placeHolderFirstItem.Controls.Find("textBoxName")* actually **placeHolderFirstItem.Controls.Count** is always zero. So I can't get textBoxName.Text  values.
I try to google that for any solution and I found some solution that I must add controls in Page.OnInit so I add controls in overridden OnInit(e):

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack) return;
            var textBoxName = new TextBox
               {
                   ID = "textBoxName",
                   CssClass = "str-search-textbox-highlight",
                   ViewStateMode = ViewStateMode.Disabled
               };
            placeHolderFirstItem.Controls.Add(textBoxName);
        }
```

after doing this I can find "textBoxName" in placeHolderFirstItem, but it fire before **DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged** !
so how can I add new controls to place holder exactly when user change the dropDownList value and how can I read new controls value?
Thanks in advance,
Mohsen.

**- Updated:**
**Here is the better solution**
(http://forums.asp.net/p/1959726/5596531.aspx?p=True&t=635244790943067485&pagenum=1)

Answer (score 0):

When you are dynamically adding controls, you have to reload the controls into the control tree everytime thereafter for it to appear.  With the help of viewstate, you could change your code sample to have:

```
ViewState("ShowTextbox") = true
```

And then in your init routine:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack) return;

        if (ViewState("ShowTextBox") == true) {
           var textBoxName = new TextBox
           {
               ID = "textBoxName",
               CssClass = "str-search-textbox-highlight",
               ViewStateMode = ViewStateMode.Disabled
           };
           placeHolderFirstItem.Controls.Add(textBoxName);
        }
    }
```

Please note it's much easier to have a control on the control tree, and then show/hide by setting Visible to true/false, because of these ASP.NET control tree issues.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but assume that we have about 10 - 15 item in dropDownList which must load their data in a new dropDownList, I don't think that it was a correct solution for hiding and showing 10 - 15 controls for every post back. I think this isn't a perfect solution.

Comment: My coded solution does not utilize the show/hide mechanism... and you are using web forms, so there aren't many options, unless you want to do everything client-side, which is even more problematic if you post back.